# Pausing a CSS animation with Jquery glitches in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a couple of bubble divs that float with a CSS animation. With jQuery i want to stop the animation when hovering, and proceeding when the user no longer hovers.

Everything works nicely in Chrome, but Firefox decides to glitch the bubble before pausing it. It looks like it's resetting the bubble animation first, before pausing.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y79h6/)

The only code that I use to pause it is this:

```
// Set the hover and hoverOut
jQuery('.bubble').hover(function () {
    // Pause the CSS animation
    jQuery(this).css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'paused')
                .css('animation-play-state', 'paused');
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
        // Run the animation again after a delay
        jQuery(this).css('-webkit-animation-play-state', 'running')
                    .css('animation-play-state', 'running')
                    .css({zIndex: jQuery(this).data('oldZindex')
        });
        next();
    });
});
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong or what i'm overlooking?

Comment: Use -moz-animation-play-state for mozilla

Comment: You're right about using that, but it works without it as well. The pausing is working as intended, it's just that the bubble moves before pausing and then snaps back when paused. It's a weird glitch that chrome doesn't show.

Comment: **Update:** I seem to be able to replicate this in Chrome as well, by removing the class (x1, x2 or x3) that holds the animation on the bubble. I don't know how to prevent it in Firefox though.. seems like Firefox is removing the animation completely while hovering. Even when I don't pause it with the above code but just change the size of the bubble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `transitions` from your `bubble CSS` it overrides your animation and starts from its initial position again try this,

**CSS**

```
div.liljon div#bubbles .bubble {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    /** your remaining background and other properties here */;
}
```

Also use `key-value pair object` in [jquery.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css) like,

```
// Set the hover and hoverOut
jQuery('.bubble').hover(function () {
    // Pause the CSS animation
    jQuery(this).css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'paused',
                      'animation-play-state': 'paused'});
}, function () {
    jQuery(this).delay(1000).queue(function (next) {
        // Run the animation again after a delay
        jQuery(this).css({'-webkit-animation-play-state': 'running',
                          'animation-play-state':'running',
                          zIndex: jQuery(this).data('oldZindex')
        });
        next();
    });
});
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/Va2d5/)